# Best way to have "alternate" gcc environment on Mint 18.1

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, gcc

Under Mint 18.1, is there a HowTo or info on how (or info that I can't/shouldn't) install a separate GCC toolchain for my own C++ noodling?

I don't want to break anything in the regular system, so don't want to look for a new PPA? or what have you to replace the 5.4 that it comes with. I fear if anything later gets recompiled in a later kernel upgrade that I would have mixed compiler binaries/libs.

Basically, I would use this new toolchain just to do my own coding on that box. Not for any system compiles.

Comment: Linux Mint is a binary installation, so as far as I know the system never uses `gcc` for anything.  However, it is tracked by the package manager, so you still shouldn't just overwrite it. See [the installation manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/), and note that I would configure with a prefix of `/opt/gcc-x.y.z` or similar.

Comment: I wondered about this because I saw during initial install when did first update, it listed a new kernel and had a note saying that it recompiles DKMs? (kernel modules) when you change kernels so if you wanted to go to an earlier one, you need to remove the higher version or would compile against wrong kernel.  --- That isn't my issue, but it made me think that when you change kernels it "recompiles" so didn't want to "replace" the mainline one. OK,  then following straight up GCC instructions is best option. Thank you - was planning on alternate, so /opt is fine by me.

Comment: If `gcc` is used by the system at all, that would be the reason.  Either way, having your personal compiler in `/opt` (or even somewhere in your home directory) is guaranteed not to conflict with that.  I have several `gcc` on my main dev machine, targeting different embedded systems

Answer (score 1):

Installing a more recent release of GCC is unlikely to break anything. There was a time when compiling Linux kernel modules under recent versions of GCC could cause weird bugs, but that was over a decade ago.

Nonetheless, to avoid taking any risk, and also to avoid package management hassles, you may well prefer to install other versions separately. I'd especially recommend this if you want to be able to test your builds with multiple compilers. Although you can have multiple versions of GCC installed, it isn't always easy to select the desired one and ensure that the default one doesn't get used for some things. Running `make CC=gcc-4.2` is easy, but it doesn't take care of `g++`, `as`, `ld`, etc., nor of commands that might hard-code a tool's name rather than go through conventional variables. To ensure that you're using a particular toolchain even with non-cooperative build scripts, put it in a separate directory and place that directory ahead of `/usr/bin` on your PATH.

The GNU-recommended way of installing GCC is to compile from source with a sequence of commands like

```
tar -xzf gcc-4.2.tar.gz
mkdir gcc-4.2-native-bin
cd gcc-4.2-native-bin
../gcc-4.2/configure --prefix /opt/gcc-4.2   # plus a target to build a cross-compiler
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I recall in earlier distro, my doing some sort of "select" command for alternates. Not sure if was Ubuntu or Gentoo or even Red Hat back in the day.  I can do the path magic, just surprised there is no way to link (combining sense, not compiler sense) a set of tools together like this G++ calls this LD etc... but I just USE this stuff, not really grok it fully.

Comment: @Varsuuk On Mint and other Debian-derived distributions, it's `update-alternatives`. Debian's alternatives has been copied or imitated in other distributions as well. But that's a system-level thing, not something you can select for an individual account, let alone to do things like build with different toolchains in parallel.

Comment: I would also recommend using `alias`es in order to use different versions. e.g. `alias c1='/opt/gcc1.0/gcc`, etc

Comment: @CedaEI That's pretty much pointless since compilers are usually invoked through build scripts.

Comment: @Gilles But scripts can be invoked with `-i` which will reduce the hassle of typing whole pathnames while writing scripts (I assume that the scripts are for local testing only)

Comment: @CedaEI I don't know which program's `-i` option you were thinking of, there are a lot of different build automation tools out there. Why would you put whole pathnames in scripts? Not only would that prevent easily switching to another compiler, but they wouldn't work on other people's machines! Even with in-house projects, it's uncommon to use absolute paths.

Comment: i meant `-i` switch of `bash` ... also what other way would the OP use to access the other `gcc` other than paths?

Comment: @CedaEI Please switch to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you want to continue this. But… wtf does an *interactive shell* (`bash -i`) have to do with *build scripts*???

Answer (score 0):

You can just upgrade the installed `gcc` binaries. Or even install several versions, I always end up with several installed for some reason (on Debian, not on Mint, but that shouldn't matter, it's the same package manager) in addition to a few cross-compilation ones.

It doesn't break anything. It even doesn't break anything if you compile the kernel yourself, like i do. I also never experienced problems with DKMS modules.

If if it *would* break anything, you can always just re-install. So no need for caution.

Comment: Heh, the "caution" would be because if it breaks on an update in 2 months, I would NOT want to go through all the work and various package installations/steps etc again. Please understand I get home earliest 7:45 and have a little guy and wife... between that and "stuff to do", and of course preternatural procrastination thanks for ADHD... who knows when/if I would reinstall. Could be a year later, like last time :)   NOT disputing your info on it not breaking anything - just explaining why can't easily reinstall once REALLY set up (I've reinstalled troubleshooting ~8 times now only initial)

Comment: I didn't mean a complete reinstall - it's enough to reinstall the gcc packages. Which is like 10 minutes. And I've been using different gcc packages and compiling my own kernel for more than 10 years, doing updates all the time, so I really doubt it will break on an update in 2 months.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood :) (because any prob/mistake at all during install - I would reinstall since was fast on my system vs 'fix') -- I mentioned running into a prob 2 months later but it could have been 2 days later - what I meant to say is "after done setting up all my normal apps/servers/etc" vs detecting prob before went through all that work. OK - will see if using the actual Mint packages is an option. I JUST finished (hour later) building 7.1 but will check it out :)